# Output of mysql query using case not as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql query as:

```
select count(srcount) as SR_Count, 
CASE assignee_name
when 'U80040300' then 'ABC'
when 'U80036396' then 'DEF'
when 'U80035831' then 'GHI'
when 'U80042986' then 'JKL'
else 'A'
end as Guys_Name
from data 
GROUP BY assignee_name;
```

Which gives output as

```
SR_COUNT    GUYS_NAME
3         A
5         A
3         GHI
2         DEF
3         ABC
2         JKL
```

But I want the output as

```
 SR_COUNT   GUYS_NAME
    8         A
    3         GHI
    2         DEF
    3         ABC
    2         JKL
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18c0ba/3)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(srcount) as SR_Count, guys_name
from
( select srcount,
CASE assignee_name
when 'U80040300' then 'ABC'
when 'U80036396' then 'DEF'
when 'U80035831' then 'GHI'
when 'U80042986' then 'JKL'
else 'A'
end as Guys_Name
from data ) as mydata
GROUP BY guys_name;
```

Just grouping needs to be on your case result.

Answer (score 2):

Group your result by `Guys_Name`

```
select count(srcount) as SR_Count, 
CASE assignee_name
when 'U80040300' then 'ABC'
when 'U80036396' then 'DEF'
when 'U80035831' then 'GHI'
when 'U80042986' then 'JKL'
else 'A'
end as Guys_Name
from data 
GROUP BY Guys_Name;
```

Comment: But since Guys_name is a `alias` it doesn't support in `Oracle SQLdeveloper`

Comment: Oracle doesnt support grouping using alias directly. It has to be subqueried first, as i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I missed the information about using Oracle Databases. So have a look at the answer from @OracleUser.